# Redireccionar a pretty URL y reescribir los parámetros como query string en el mismo .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, pretty-urls

Tengo la siguiente la siguiente URL

```
http://www.prueba.com/?page_id=1785&match=ATLETICO_DE_MADRID_VS_REAL_MADRID
```

En mi configuración de htaccess logro que cada vez que yo escribo esto me redirige a la siguiente url

```
http://www.prueba.com/marcador/ATLETICO_DE_MADRID_VS_REAL_MADRID/
```

El problema viene cuando necesito mostrar los datos de la primera url con la liga de la segunda, dado que me muestra un error 404

Muestro mi archivo .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=1785&match=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ marcador/%1/? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^marcador/(.*)$ ?page_id=1785&match=ATLETICO_DE_MADRID_VS_REAL_MADRID [QSA,END]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

¿Alguien podría auxiliarme en encontrar en qué tengo el fallo?

Answer (score 1):

Falta especificar hacia dónde se está reescribiendo, cambiando:

```
RewriteRule ^marcador/(.*)$ ?page_id=1785&match=ATLETICO_DE_MADRID_VS_REAL_MADRID [QSA,END]
```

por:

```
RewriteRule ^marcador/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?page_id=1785&match=$1 [QSA,END]
```